# Extend measure so it occupies whole line

Tags: lilypond

I am writing some exercises, for my students.

Those are mostly one line examples, and this time I need a measure to extend over whole line, so one big measure with ending bar, nothing else.

What do I need to override to obtain this effect?

Here is my sample exercise, showing blank guitar strings:

```
    music = \relative c' {
        \clef treble
        \key c \major

        % enter your music here
        e,1\6 a\5 d\4 g\3 b\2 e\1 \break
    }
```

This ends on about half page width, and I would like it to take whole line.

**addition**
I also added this, because I do not need barlines in this example, nor time signature.

```
    \score {

        \new Staff \with {
            fontSize = #+1
                \override StaffSymbol.staff-space = #(magstep +1)
                \omit TimeSignature
                \omit BarLine
        } \music

        \layout {
            ragged-right = ##t
        }
        \midi {}
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, was because of bad formatting.

Answer (score 8):

After changing

```
    \layout {
        ragged-right = ##t
    }
```

to

```
    \layout {
        ragged-right = ##f
    }
```

it works!